# Help in KERAS, a model.fit method on a array 50x50 slows the system, how can I make it faster?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, reinforcement-learning

i m a new member and i am a student. i have a problem. how can I make this training faster my neural network ? when I call the fit method on a 100 x 100 matrix goes very slow

my model it's a sequential

```
def build_model(env, **opt):
loss = opt.get('loss', 'mse')
a = opt.get('alpha', 0.24)
model = Sequential()
esize = env.maze.size
model.add(Dense(esize, input_shape=(esize,)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=a))
model.add(Dense(esize))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=a))
model.add(Dense(num_actions))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
return model
```

this is my Experience Class

```
def __init__(self, model, max_memory=100, discount=0.97):
    self.model = model
    self.max_memory = max_memory
    self.discount = discount
    self.memory = list()
    self.num_actions = model.output_shape[-1]

def remember(self, episode):
    # episode = [env_state, action, reward, next_env_state, game_over]
    # memory[i] = episode
    # env_state == flattened 1d maze cells info, including agent cell (see method: observe)
    self.memory.append(episode)
    if len(self.memory) > self.max_memory:
        del self.memory[0]

def predict(self, env_state):
    return self.model.predict(env_state)[0]

def get_data(self, data_size=10):
    env_size = self.memory[0][0].shape[1]   # env_state 1d size (1st element of episode)
    mem_size = len(self.memory)
    data_size = min(mem_size, data_size)
    inputs = np.zeros((data_size, env_size))
    targets = np.zeros((data_size, self.num_actions))
    for i, j in enumerate(np.random.choice(range(mem_size), data_size, replace=False)):
        env_state, action, reward, next_env_state, game_over = self.memory[j]
        inputs[i] = env_state
        # There should be no target values for actions not taken.
        # Thou shalt not correct actions not taken #deep (quote by Eder Santana)
        targets[i] = self.predict(env_state)
        # Q_sa = derived policy = max quality env/action = max_a' Q(s', a')
        Q_sa = np.max(self.predict(next_env_state))
        if game_over:
            targets[i, action] = reward
        else:
            # reward + gamma * max_a' Q(s', a')
            targets[i, action] = reward + self.discount * Q_sa
    return inputs, targets
```

when i call model.fit , the system speed slows

```
 h = self.model.fit(
        inputs,
        targets,
        epochs = epochs,
        batch_size=16,
        verbose=0,
    )
```

the matrix that i step to it is

```
n = 50

def build(n):

mat=np.ones(n*n)

return mat.reshape((n,n))
```

should I modify the template by adding more Danse layers? I don’t know how to improve the performance because I would like to call it on a 100x100 matrix

Comment: Looking at your model definition it seems both you input layer and hidden layer have a number of neurons equal to `esize` (which is `100 x 100 = 10000` if I understand correctly). This will lead to a weights matrix of size (`10000, 10000`), which is obviously very large. Try decreasing the number of neurons in the hidden layer to something like 100 or even lower, I expect this to speed things up quite a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much , but I don’t know why but it returns this error, there is something that forces me to set [ 10000 ,10000],the error is  "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and 49. Shapes are [10000,100] and [10000,10000]. for 'Assign_2' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [10000,100], [10000,10000]."